# Consulta anidada con if en mysql

Tags: mysql

Necesito hacer una consulta anidada pero bajo una condición. Verán tengo dos tablas.

```
Tabla 1-> usuarios_administradores
Tabla 2-> usuarios_colaboradores
```

La tabla que me presenta el inconveniente es la de "`agenda_eventos`". Agenda_eventos tiene un campo que se llama "`tipo`", si el tipo es 1, tengo que obtener el correo desde la tabla "`usuarios_administradores`", pero si "tipo"=0 , el email lo tengo que obtener desde la tabla "`usuarios_colaboradores`".

El resultado que necesito es algo así (Todos los campos son de la tabla agenda_eventos, excepto el email, ese se debe obtener según el tipo y el id del usuario):

```
idevento, idempresa, idusaurio, tipousuario, titulo, emailusuario
```

Esta es mi tabla de "`agenda_ventos`"

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_empresa   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id_usuario   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| titulo       | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| descripcion  | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| allDay       | int(1)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| inicio_fecha | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fin_fecha    | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| inicio_hora  | time         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fin_hora     | time         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tipo_evento  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tipo_usuario | int(1)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| recordar     | tinyint(4)   | YES  |     | 1       |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Siguiendo este artículo intento hacer lo siguiente, sin embargo, el resultado es un error. :/  No se si haya alguna otra recomendación para esto. Agradecería infinitamente su orientación:

```
    select agenda.id, agenda.id_empresa, agenda.id_usuario, agenda.tipo_usuario,  agenda.titulo, 
(select email if(agenda.tipo_usuario=1 && agenda.id_usuario=empresas_usuariosprincipales.id)from empresas_usuariosprincipales)
from agenda_eventos as agenda where recordar = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre que en `usuarios_administradores` y en `usuarios_colaboradores` tengas solo una fila por usuario, lo más practico es conectar a la consulta principal las dos tablas mediante un `left join`. Voy a suponer, por que no lo has indicado, que los ID de usuarios en las dos tablas es también `id_usuario`, para obtener el correo según `agenda.tipo_usuario`, además de los `left join` a las dos tablas, usaremos un `case` para determinar de dónde obtenemos el correo:

```
select  case when agenda.tipo_usuario = 1 then adm.email when agenda.tipo_usuario = 0 then colab.email end as 'correo'
    from agenda_eventos as agenda
    left join usuarios_administradores as adm
        on agenda.id_usuario = adm.id_usuario
    left join usuarios_colaboradores as colab
        on agenda.id_usuario = colab.id_usuario
    where recordar = 1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, solo para aclarar. ¿Es posible hacer condiciones tipo como lo que estaba haciendo o definitivamente no es recomendable? Gracias.

Comment: Si, es posible agregar una subconsulta a nivel de columna, pero deberías agregar a la misma las dos tablas que intervienen y luego decidir que correo usar en función del tipo de usuario, dejar esta lógica a nivel de columna suele traer problemas de performance. Saludos

Comment: Patricio si hubiera la posibilidad de un `tipo_usuario=3` o un `tipo_usuario=N` no va a funcionar de la forma esperada. En esta consulta, lo que hará será buscar todos los `tipo_usuario` que no sean `1` en la tabla de colaboradores. Creo que conviene un filtro específico por cada tipo. Aunque hoy haya sólo dos tipos de usuario, en un futuro las cosas pueden evolucionar, se pueden crear para 2019 otros dos tipos de usuario y ya estaríamos teniendo serios problemas con esta consulta.

Comment: @A.Cedano si claro, estoy de acuerdo que el modelo no es el más óptimo, y es cierto que ser especifico siempre es mejor, agrego tu comentario a la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que puedes resolverlo al menos de dos maneras.

Una sería usando `LEFT OUTER JOIN` con cada tabla, donde pondrías también las condiciones del tipo. En cuanto la columna, la comprobarías con `IFNULL`, así te mostrará cualquiera de las dos sin importar de qué tabla haya venido:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.id_empresa, 
    a.id_usuario, 
    a.tipo_usuario,  
    a.titulo,
    IFNULL(ua.email, uc.email) email
FROM agenda a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN usuarios_administradores ua ON (a.id_usuario = ua.id_usuario AND a.tipo = 1)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN usuarios_colaboradores uc ON (a.id_usuario = uc.id_usuario AND a.tipo = 0)
    WHERE a.recordar=1;
```

Otra forma de hacerlo sería con `COALESCE`. Es casi lo mismo, sólo que se cambia el `IFNULL` por `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.id_empresa, 
    a.id_usuario, 
    a.tipo_usuario,  
    a.titulo,
    COALESCE(ua.email, uc.email) email
FROM agenda a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN usuarios_administradores ua ON (a.id_usuario = ua.id_usuario AND a.tipo = 1)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN usuarios_colaboradores uc ON (a.id_usuario = uc.id_usuario AND a.tipo = 0)
    WHERE a.recordar=1;
```

**NOTA**:

En la pregunta no quedan claros algunos nombres de columna. En la descripción de la tabla pones que la columna se llama `tipo_evento`, pero en el planteamiento hablas de una columna llamada `tipo`, que es la que he usado. Tampoco queda claro cómo se llama la columna que sirve de enlace en las tablas `ua` y `uc`, yo he usado `id_usuario`. Si no se llaman así, debes usar los nombres reales en ambos casos.

También he usado *alias*  cortos para las tablas (`a, ua, uc`), de forma que la consulta no sea tan engorrosa.

Comment: En efecto he omitido unos datos por error de dedo (tipo_evento es el correcto id para ambas tablas de usuarios es el correcto), sin embargo, he tomado tus recomendaciones, tu ejemplo me sirve a la perfección, te agradezco infinitamente.

Comment: @NeftaliAcosta me alegro de que te haya servido. Olvidé de decir que quizá convendría plantear un diseño distinto de las tablas. Me parece que no es normal tener que dar tantas vueltas para obtener un email. Es sólo una opinión, la cual dejo caer para que lo pienses. Aunque es cierto que, según tu contexto podría estar justificado el hacerlo así. Yo preguntaría por ejemplo, ¿por qué no hay una sola tabla `usuario` por ejemplo, o una tabla `persona` que agrupe todo lo que es común a una persona?

Comment: Entiendo tu postura, sin embargo así me entregaron la tabla y me es más fácil solucionarlo con una consulta a invertir tiempo (que de momento no lo tengo ) en hacer esa corrección. Agradezco nuevamente tu comentario pues me has ayudado bastante, sobre todo para próximas actualizaciones.

Comment: @A.Cedano permiteme hacer una observación, esta solución tiene un solo eventual problema, que solo el OP podría decirnos, que es el caso que los `id` de usuarios se repitan entre tablas.